# Code Igniter CLI vs crontab entry

Tags: codeigniter, command-line-interface, cron

When I launch a CodeIgniter controller via CLI, like so:

```
php index.php mycontroller method
```

everything works well (assume you are on the right paths, inside the code igniter folder)

However, when the same line is invoked from a crontab entry, the default controller is executed (as if the below line was asked)

```
php index.php welcome
```

I've attempted to create a bootstrap for my cron needs and done extensive research into this topic, to no avail.
One of the solutions attempted: http://www.asim.pk/2009/05/14/creating-and-installing-crontabs-using-codeigniter/

Code Igniter version: Reactor 2.0.2

Do you know why Code Igniter would react differently in CLI mode vs crontab? Olde versions of CI seems to operate well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something that normally works, does not work when called from crontab it is nearly always a path issue.

Using /usr/local/bin/php instead of just php will make it work. The same is true for system calls inside the php script e.g. passthru, system, exec etc.

You can use the whereis command to find the absolute path to the executable you want to run by running e.g.:

```
whereis php
```

Comment: thanks CodeReaper, this did the trick. I changed the php path (/usr/local/bin/php) and now is working as expected